# USB flash disk not mounting/showing and gparted and commands didn't output while connecting the USB drive - UBUNTU 16.04

Tags: linux, mount, usb, disk, gparted

I have a 8GB San Disk Cruzer Blade flash disk. When I connected it, it is not mounting. So I opened the Disks; it shows:

[image]

Then I tried opening Gparted; it never finishes loading. When I realised this won't complete, I opened the Terminal and tried to view the output of `sudo blkid` and `sudo fdisk -l`; the cursor kept blinking when I pressed enter after typing the first command. I waited for couple of minutes and no change. 
I tried the second command and it gave

```
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes Disklabel type: gpt Disk identifier: F4F92FF1-7976-4C15-949F-ECE869B7C5F1

Device          Start        End   Sectors   Size Type

/dev/sda1        2048    1050623   1048576   512M EFI System 
/dev/sda2 1050624  196558847 195508224  93.2G Linux filesystem 
/dev/sda3   196558848  930086911 733528064 349.8G Linux filesystem 
/dev/sda4   930086912  949618687  19531776   9.3G Linux swap 
/dev/sda5   949618688 1144930303 195311616  93.1G Microsoft basic data 
/dev/sda6  1144930304 1340241919 195311616  93.1G Linux filesystem 
/dev/sda7  1340241920 1953523711 613281792 292.4G Linux filesystem
```

and after the last line the cursor keep blinking. After waiting some time, I disconnected the device and the cursor returned [NOTE : ctl +c or ctl +z was not working]. I tried to shutdown the system, and that also got stuck:

[image]

The USB drive was working fine some hour ago. How can I get these commands to work with my USB drive?

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks very much like **you've run into a hardware problem and your USB stick is broken**, thus off-topic here as we don't deal with hardware problems, only Unix/Linux problems.  *We're very sorry*

Comment: I don't think this is a hardware problem. I faced similar things before where a connected hard drive freezes the whole system until it's disconnected. Is your system up to date? Try `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y` then reboot and try again.